# Style input element when pristine in Angular

Tags: css, angular

Hi I have this css class that gives a red border when the input field is required and the input field is invalid. This changes to green when the input field becomes valid.

**CSS**

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Vehicle Code"
              [formControl]="codeControl"
              required
            />
```

What I need now is to set the left border to other color when it hasn't been touched yet. Because with what I have right now, on page load, the default left border is red and changes to green when validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle or ngClass.

For this example I have used ngClass ( my preferred method ).

Component.css:

```
.valid {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948;
}

.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442;
}
```

Component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    [formControl]="name" 
    [ngClass]="{'required': name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched), 'valid': name.valid && (name.dirty || name.touched)}"
  >
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor() { }

  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  get name(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('name')
  } 
}
```

I have put a Stackblitz here for your reference too, below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xsg7r

Happy Coding :-)